# How to make Django custom user model an abstract class

Tags: python, django

I have created my own custom user model in django and specified the same in settings.py :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userprofile.User'
```

After this, I created ***User*** as an abstract class since I wanted to have two separate classes derived from this class namely - ***Vendor*** and ***Customer***. This will create two separate database tables.

The problem occurs when I created another class - ***ProductReview***. This class needs a foreign key to the user who added the review and this user can be either a ***Vendor*** or a ***Customer***. I am not sure how to put this foreign key constraint here, because ***settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL*** will not work, as ***User*** is an abstract class.

Following is the class structure:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

class User(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Vendor(User):

class Customer(User):

class ProductReview(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='reviews', null=True, blank=True)
```

**Edit** - I went ahead with three different tables for each of the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case I would consider changing my modeling. This how I would do it:

- Leave the default `User` as the auth user model for Django.
- Create a `Vendor` and a `Customer` class with one-to-one relationship to the `User` model in order to extend it.

In this way, a you can have a `ProductReview` to reference a `User`, who could be either a `Vendor` or a `Customer`, or you can reference `Customer`s only if you wish.

See more on [Django documentation: Extending the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of user field in `ProductReview` model class will map with the `USER` model. To define whether it is a `Vendor` or a `Customer` you need to declare another field probably integer field with mapping declared as

```
TYPE_OF_USER_MAPPING = {
    1: 'Vendor',
    2: 'Customer'
}
```

and then create a query to check in which model `Vendor` or `Customer` the original `USER` is.

Comment: is it okay to go ahead with this model or should i consider creating separate db tables for all of the three models (User, Vendor, Customer). If i do this, then i can map reviews directly to User. But, i am not sure if i will be able to get Vendor details from User if i do this.

Comment: Moreover, we cannot map ProductReview model to an abstract model - User.

Comment: The USER model should be abstract because it consists of all the users. The Vendor and Customer model should be inheriting this USER model and the Product Review model should accordingly contain those fields. This will maintain the database normalization.